# How best to remove <div> tag wrapper around inserted images

Tags: php, dom, preg-replace

I have the following HTML:

```
<div><p><img src="https://test1.jpg" /></p></div>
<p>aaa</p>
<p>bbb</p>
<p>ccc<div>ddd <img src="http://test2.jpg" /></div></p>
<p>eee</p>
<p>fff</p>
<p>ggg</p>
<p>hhh</p>
<p>iii</p>
<div><p><img src="https://test3.jpg" /></p></div>
```

But I need to remove the `div` tag around the image outside the `p` tag; the expected output is:

```
<p><img src="https://test1.jpg" /></p>
<p>aaa</p>
<p>bbb</p>
<p>ccc<div>ddd <img src="http://test2.jpg" /></div></p>
<p>eee</p>
<p>fff</p>
<p>ggg</p>
<p>hhh</p>
<p>iii</p>
<p><img src="https://test3.jpg" /></p>
```

Does anybody know how to do it with PHP `preg_replace` function?

Comment: what about `<p>ccc<div>ddd <img src="http://test2.jpg" /></div></p>`???, Here is a `div`  as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you really dont want to use regex to do this, you should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.  Whilst this seems longer and more complicated, its much more secure.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = '<div><p><img src="https://test1.jpg" /></p></div>ccc<div>ddd <img src="http://test2.jpg" /></div>';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName( 'div' ) as $node) {
     // this bit is a little hacky, but if you can predict the values use it to exclude some items
     if(strpos($node->nodeValue, 'ddd') !== false) {
         continue;
     }

     $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
     while($node->childNodes->length > 0) {
        $fragment->appendChild($node->childNodes->item(0));
     }

     $node->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment,$node);
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();

echo $html;
```

[sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce45b5ab72bce23f1b95b6b0cfb49378ce79a2a8)